# Trying to replace some text on my html page with input from a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to create a page where the user enters some setup (flight number &status)
Then the input from the form is displayed on the page using JavaScript
Initially it work using the document.write function but that just killed the css by overwriting everything so now I’m trying to use the replace function in JavaScript to do this but it’s not working
Here’s the code i uses

`

```
`<h1>flight status update</h1>
      <form onsubmit="rep(document.getElementById('FlightNumber').value,document.getElementById('Flightstatus').value)">
        Flight Number: <input type="text" name="a" id="FlightNumber"><br>
        Flight status: <input type="text" name="flightStatus" id="Flightstatus"><br>
        <p>hello</p>
      <button >submit</button>
      </form>
    <!-- </div> -->`

</body>
```

```
`//js script starts here
 function Flight(flightNumber, status) {
    this.number =flightNumber;
     this.status =status;
  };
  document.write('The flight ' + flight1.number + ' is ' + flight1.status);


        function rep(FlightNumber, Flightstatus) {

          document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace("hello","The flight ' + FlightNumber + ' is ' + Flightstatus");
                }`
```

Please help me with either a better way to do this or please correct me where i went wrong

Hoping to find a better of not easier way to do this particular task of taking input from a form and displaying it on the page it self without stopping the css

Comment: I would check out a good source of information about JavaScript such as https://developer.mozilla.org. If you check out `document.write()` there (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) you can see they discourage using that method. I would take that advice. There are good tutorials  at MDN on JavaScript for beginners and intermediate programmers.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting
  let flightNumber = document.getElementById("FlightNumber").value;
  let flightStatus = document.getElementById("Flightstatus").value;
  let flightDetails = `The flight ${flightNumber} is ${flightStatus}`;
  document.getElementById("message").innerText = flightDetails;
});
```

```html
<h1>flight status update</h1>
<form id="myform">
  <label for="FlightNumber">Flight Number: </label><input type="text" name="a" id="FlightNumber"><br>
  <label for="Flightstatus">Flight status: </label><input type="text" name="flightStatus" id="Flightstatus"><br>
  <p>hello</p>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<p id="message"></p>
```

As @user3425506 said it is generally not recommended to use document.write()

Instead a simple approach for this case is to

1. Use EventHandlers to capture the Submit [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) in a form
2. Bind the Submit event with your function to perform your custom logic
3. Format the flight details I used [template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
4. Show the Formatted data to an existing element in the HTML in this case `message`

EDIT: This is the full HTML I used and it works fine in chrome and firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>flight status update</h1>
    <form id="myform">
        <label for="FlightNumber">Flight Number: </label><input type="text" name="a" id="FlightNumber"><br>
        <label for="Flightstatus">Flight status: </label><input type="text" name="flightStatus" id="Flightstatus"><br>
        <p>hello</p>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id="message"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting
            let flightNumber = document.getElementById("FlightNumber").value;
            let flightStatus = document.getElementById("Flightstatus").value;
            let flightDetails = `The flight ${flightNumber} is ${flightStatus}`;
            document.getElementById("message").innerText = flightDetails;
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Copied your code but it didn’t work for my browser (google chrome)after submitting it refreshes the page instead of displaying the intended content like it does here

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped me to understand so much